# Python not recognising duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

A sample snapshot of first 5 rows of 2 data sets that I have
Emp1 dataframe:

```
Name
--------
John
Matt
Anish
Dave
Mike
```

Emp2 dataframe:

```
Name
--------
Sue
Matt
Raj
Dave
Simon
```

I concatenated both (converting them to objects in the process just in case)

```
 Con=pd.concat(emp1.astype(str),emp2.astype(str))
Con
Name
-----
John
Matt
Anish
Dave
Mike
Sue
Matt
Raj
Dave
Simon
```

However, python doesn't seem think Matt and Dave are duplicates for some reason

```
Con.duplicated()
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

I also tried outer joining using pd.merge but still the duplicates are not recognized.I want to compare the master Emp1 with Emp2 and find which names in Emp1 are not in Emp2. So my logic is to merge/concatenate both and select the values which are not duplicates. The data is read from excel.

Many Thanks

Comment: Try df.to_string().split('\n') and see if there are any spacing issues with the names maybe

Comment: you can strip whitespace with `str.strip()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is possible some trailing whitespaces, so remove them:

```
df1['name'] = df1['name'].str.strip()
df2['name'] = df2['name'].str.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I repeated your steps:

```
> import pandas as pd
> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["John", "Matt", "Anish", "Dave", "Mike"]})
> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Sue", "Matt", "Raj", "Dave", "Simon"]})
> df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
> df3.duplicated()
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: yes but the problem happens when the data is read from the excel.